# launch powershell with command via cmd

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd

how to start, a program with the arguments using powershell via cmd 
:)

```
powershell -command "& {get-service -computername server1,server2 -displayname 'instance *'|where {$_.status -eq 'Running'}|foreach-object {start-process -filepath 'C:\monitor.exe' -argumentlist "-adminhost $($_.machinename) -servername $($_.name)"} } "
```

Now when replacing "  " with the carts on '  ' program I get a text representation of variables

```
-argumentlist "-adminhost $($_.machinename) -servername $($_.name)"
```

is it possible to write such a command powershell starts the process with parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option would be to write the PowerShell code to a file and run that:

```
powershell.exe -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"
```

If you must execute a command string with nested double quotes you need to escape the nested double quotes with backslashes:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{Write-Output \"foo bar\"}"
```

In your case:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{Get-Service -ComputerName server1,server2 -DisplayName 'instance *'|where {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}|ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\monitor.exe' -ArgumentList \"-adminhost $($_.MachineName) -servername $($_.Name)\"}}"
```

Or, since the individual arguments don't seem to contain spaces, you could pass the argument list as an actual list/array:

```
powershell.exe -Command "&{Get-Service -ComputerName server1,server2 -DisplayName 'instance *'|where {$_.Status -eq 'Running'}|ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\monitor.exe' -ArgumentList '-adminhost', $_.MachineName, '-servername', $_.Name}}"
```